# Do you have to instantiate the object to use it in the Immediate window?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

If I have a console application containing the class

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

I can go into the immediate window at design time and do

> new HelloWorld().Hello()

But, if I try

> ? Hello()

I get error "The name 'Hello' does not exist in the current context".  So it appears I need to instantiate the class first.  That makes sense.

But, my confusion comes from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) documentation where they show

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        MyFunction(5)
    End Sub

    Function MyFunction(ByVal input as Integer) As Integer
        Return input * 2
    End Function

End Module
```

They say all you have to do is type

> ?MyFunction(2) in the Immediate window and press Enter.

I'm not a VB.NET guy. Am I correct in assuming I need to instantiate my object first?  Why does the VB.NET example differ?

Comment: paste the full Main(strings args[]) section so we can see you only have new HelloWorld().Hello() what object variable are you assigning to new HelloWorld().Hello()

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - No object assignment is made.  I'm creating an instance on the fly just to call Hello.  In JavaScript they call it cascading.  I don't know if there's a proper term in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in a Module, not in a class. Modules are leftovers from the days of yore (i.e., VB6).

Comment: :-) It's funny... Doesn't it make you wonder why you used VB6 for so long?

Comment: Some people still do (not me). Modules are still available in VB.Net 10

Comment: that's why true coders code in C# vs the interpreted language like VB.. my advice.. switch to C#

Comment: VB.NET is not interpreted, it's compiled just like C#. That is why you can call VB.NET code from C# and any other .NET Language; they both compile MSIL code that runs on the CLR.